# How to retrieve value of promise in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I using fetch for post data to controller in Asp.Net Core. This is my fetch code

```
fetch(url, {
            method: method,
            credentials: "include",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
            },
            body: formData
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    successMessage.innerHTML = response.StatusMessage;
                } else {
                    FailedMessage.innerHTML = response.StatusMessage;
                    console.log(response, response.json())
                    throw Error(response.statusText);
                }
            })
            .then(data => console.log('data is', data))
```

And this code output in console like this

```
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Object
IsSuccess: false
StatusMessage: "User name 'xxxx' is already taken."
__proto__: Object
```

I want to retrieve `StatusMessage` if promise resolved.
How can I retrieve `StatusMessage` property from promise to javascript?

Comment: `data.StatusMessage`

Answer (score 0):

Since StatusMessage is part of the response JSON, you need to get the response data before you can access it

```
fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
    },
    body: formData
})
.then(response => response.json().then(data => ({data, ok:response.ok})))
.then(({data, ok}) => {
    if (ok) {
        successMessage.innerHTML = response.StatusMessage;
    } else {
        FailedMessage.innerHTML = response.StatusMessage;
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
});
```

The code

```
.then(response => response.json().then(data => ({data, ok:response.ok})))
```

results in an object `{data, ok}` - so you can access the `ok` flag in the second `.then`